# How to mirror trunk of svn repo into github?

Tags: git, svn, github

What is the best way to mirror trunk of some external svn repo into github? I don't intend to make any commits to that project, just want to keep everything needed in one place.

Answer (score 3):

I think this should work

```
git svn clone -T trunk https://SVN_REPO
git remote add github GITHUB_REPO
git push github master
```

after this initial step you can do

```
git svn rebase
git push github master
```

Comment: what i want is to mirror all svn branches, your method is not the one that i want

Answer (score 0):

There is a handy migration script for doing this called [sync2git](https://github.com/dpocock/sync2git)

When you use rebase, you must tell it to fetch all.

```
git svn rebase \
--fetch-all \
-A "${AUTHORS_FILE}"
```

Then it's a matter of tagging the references and creating branches. See the script for a better example.